# Is there a way to assign files as variables in python

Tags: python-3.x, file, variables

help my code keeps giving me a name error for my lyrics value, for context the external file contains a single character

I have tried editing the external files as well as alternate ways to open the file in hand

this is the code snippet which is relevant:

```
with open("lyrics" ,"r")  as lyrics:

lyrics=lyrics.read()


while counter>=1:

  print(lyrics.read([0]),"    ",lyrics.read([-0]))
```

Comment: You should change the line - with open("lyrics", "r") as `file`  to avoid the name conflict and confusing. Then next line it could be like this -  `lines = file.read()`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including complete code and the full error with traceback. In this code, `counter` is not defined, so maybe that explains the NameError. You can [edit] the question. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: i tried this but it did not solve the problem, i still get the error that lyrics is not defined, thanks anyway